# MySQL queries to select messages related to a user, using UNION vs. OR

Tags: performance, sql, mysql, comparative-review

I'm just wondering if there is any improvements that can be made on my queries, as i've looked around and posts are saying to use `UNION ALL` instead of `OR` but with the performance times it looking like the `OR` condition works out better.

Could anyone please give me some advise on improving my queries?

**Using UNION ALL:**

Time taken: `Showing rows 0 - 1 (2 total, Query took 0.0016 seconds.)`

```
(SELECT direct_message.*
       FROM `direct_message`
       INNER JOIN direct_message_thread ON direct_message_thread.chat_id = direct_message.id
       WHERE direct_message.recipient_id = '10896'
         AND direct_message.school_id = '1'
         AND direct_message_thread.school_id = direct_message.school_id
       GROUP BY direct_message.id
       ORDER BY direct_message_thread.inserted DESC)
    UNION ALL
      (SELECT direct_message.*
       FROM `direct_message`
       INNER JOIN direct_message_thread ON direct_message_thread.chat_id = direct_message.id
       WHERE direct_message.creator_id = '10896'
         AND direct_message.school_id = '1'
         AND direct_message_thread.school_id = direct_message.school_id
       GROUP BY direct_message.id
       ORDER BY direct_message_thread.inserted DESC)
    UNION ALL
      (SELECT direct_message.*
       FROM `direct_message`
       LEFT JOIN direct_message_group ON direct_message_group.chat_id = direct_message.id
       INNER JOIN direct_message_thread ON direct_message_thread.chat_id = direct_message.id
       WHERE direct_message_group.staff_id = '10896'
         AND direct_message.school_id = '1'
         AND direct_message_thread.school_id = direct_message.school_id
       GROUP BY direct_message.id
       ORDER BY direct_message_thread.inserted DESC)
```

**EXPLAIN OF QUERY**

[image]

**Using OR:**

Time taken: `Showing rows 0 - 1 (2 total, Query took 0.0011 seconds.)`

```
SELECT direct_message.*,
       IFNULL(direct_message_group.staff_id, 0) AS staff_id
FROM `direct_message`
LEFT JOIN direct_message_group ON direct_message_group.chat_id = direct_message.id
INNER JOIN direct_message_thread ON direct_message_thread.chat_id = direct_message.id
WHERE ((direct_message.recipient_id = '10896'
        OR direct_message.creator_id = '10896'
        OR (direct_message_group.staff_id = '10896'
            AND direct_message_group.active = '0')))
  AND direct_message.school_id = '1'
  AND direct_message_thread.school_id = direct_message.school_id
GROUP BY direct_message.id
ORDER BY direct_message_thread.inserted DESC
LIMIT 0,
      25
```

**EXPLAIN OF QUERY**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OR` is really bad in Joins, in `WHERE` it can/should be replaced when the optimizer doesn't use indexes (and `OR` does).

I would prefer the Union for a simple reason, it's easier to write/understand/extend. Additionally the first two Selects are the same besides one condition, so combining them is simple.

And using aliases really simplifies reading the code.

```
  (SELECT dm.*
   FROM `direct_message`AS dm
   INNER JOIN direct_message_thread AS dmt
      ON dmt.chat_id = dm.id
     AND dmt.school_id = dm.school_id -- moved from WHERE as this is a join condition 
   WHERE (dm.recipient_id = '10896' OR dm.creator_id = '10896')
     AND dm.school_id = '1'
   GROUP BY dm.id
   ORDER BY dmt.inserted DESC)

UNION ALL

  (SELECT dm.*
   FROM `direct_message` AS dm
   INNER JOIN direct_message_thread AS dmt
      ON dmt.chat_id = dm.id
     AND dmt.school_id = dm.school_id
   INNER JOIN direct_message_group AS dmg
      ON dmg.chat_id = dm.id
   WHERE dmg.staff_id = '10896'
     AND dm.school_id = '1'
   GROUP BY dm.id
   ORDER BY dmt.inserted DESC)
```